# nginx location matches multiple times

Tags: nginx, nginx-location, nginx-config

My nginx.conf looks something like this

```
server {
  listen 443 ssl;
  server_name test.com;
  client_max_body_size 100M;

  # test.com/ should be a static page
  location = / {
    root /var/www/
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    break;
  }

  # everything else should go to the upstream app server
  location / {
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
  }
}
```

My issue is that when I visit `test.com` nginx seems to evaluate the `location /` block as well because it's proxying the request to my upstream server rather than stopping at the `location = /` block. I've tried including `break;` in the `location = /` block and that didn't change the behavior at all. I know it's matching the first `location = /` block because the request that I see on my app server is for `/index.html` which is presumably rewritten by the `try_file` directive (if I change that to `/foo.html` instead, I see it reflected on my app server).

I've tried nginx location testing tools like https://nginx.viraptor.info and that said the final match should only be the "exact match" described by the `location = /` block.

And yes, I've restarted nginx after every time I changed config file.

Anyone have any clue why this is happening? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What `nginx -t` says?

Comment: Is it an option to switch to the "good" pattern under "Proxy Everything" as listed here: https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/config_pitfalls/ I know, it is not exactly what you asked for, but maybe it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nginx processes two URIs, first the `/` and then the internally rewritten `/index.html`. Your configuration processes the second URI in the `location /` block.

Either, add an exact match `location` for the second URI, for example:

```
root /var/www;
location = / { ... }
location = /index.html { }
location / { ... }
```

Or, you can arrange for `try_files` to process the URI within the same location:

```
root /var/www;
location = / { 
    try_files /index.html =404;
}
location / { ... }
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files) for details.