# nginx '= /' not matching '/'

Tags: nginx, nginx-config, nginx-location

I have the following server, and it's the only server on my conf

```
    server {
    listen 8080;
    server_name _;

    location / {
        set $dest http://api_backend;
        set $dest_host 127.0.0.1;
        add_header X-route '= /';

    }

}
```

The X-route header is just to check if it goes inside, I make a request to http://localhost:8080/ but it's not going inside, however if I remove the `=` and just leave `location /` then it does enter. Could anyone help me on why this is happening? I want to match exactly `/` and not every other route in existence here.

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53907427/4862445)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems I need to set `= /index.html` instead of just `= /`.